# React how to toggle onclick to false after you already clicked?

Tags: reactjs

Edit: Figured it out. I updated the answer at the bottom

So I figured out how to change my class to active whenever I click on my icon, but I'm not sure how I'd change it to false whenever I click it again?

```
class NavbarItems extends Component {
state = { clicked: false}

handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ clicked: true })
}

 render() {
    return (
        <nav className="NavbarItems">
            <h1 className="navbar-logo">Startup</h1>
            <div className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
```

How would I change the ul className back to 'nav-menu' after I clicked on the menu icon?

Right now when I click on it, it adds the active class, but I don't know how to remove that active class whenever I click again

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(clicked => (
        { clicked: !clicked.clicked }
    ))
    }
```

Comment: If value of `clicked:true` then it must be active else for `false` must be inactive and so you should toggle previous clicked state on every click. So you need the previous state. The setState, when used as function way, provides you with the previous state as an argument. The function must return an object that will be merged to state.
`this.setState( (prevState) => ({ clicked: !prevState.clicked }));`

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I put at the bottom of my question. I ended up figuring it out and added my answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your handleClick to this:

```
handleClick = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    clicked: !prevState.clicked
  }))
}
```

Comment: that didn't work. I figured it out from looking at the react docs, I had to add another function first and pass in the parameter

Comment: Thanks for the improveent on my post. I forgot this is a class component not a functional one :)

Answer (score 0):

Use classnames https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

```
npm install classnames --save
```

In your component

```
import cx from 'classnames';

class NavbarItems extends Component {
state = { clicked: false}

handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked })
}

 render() {
    return (
        <nav className="NavbarItems">
            <h1 className="navbar-logo">Startup</h1>
            <div className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <ul className={cx('nav-menu', {['active']: this.state.clicked})}>
```

Comment: what's the purpose of importing classnames? seems like the code is much harder to read and understand

Comment: Its an utility function for conditionally joining the classNames. It helps you to add or remove dynamic classes deponds on your condition.

Comment: can you link the reactdocs talking about it? I'm new so I never seen that before

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
 handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked });
  };
```